# WPF popup closing before treeview selection

Tags: wpf, treeview, selecteditem

I'm working on a project with a treeview inside a popup.  I need to have it where the popup remains open until a selection is made on the treeview.  At first I tried controlling this with selectedItemChanged on the treeview, then MouseLeave, but if you overshoot the popup by just a pixel, it closes without you being able to make a selection on the treeview.

I'm looking to do something such as"

```
if (dirTree.SelectedItem = "")
     { 
       popup1.IsOpen = true; 
     }
       popup1.IsOpen = false;
```

but that gives me "Possible unintended reference comparison; to get a value comparison, cas t the left hand side to type 'string'."

I've been searching using "treeview any selected" "treeview SelectedItem", etc.  Admittedly it may just be a simple syntax issue because I'm new to C# and WPF.

Comment: Have you tried if (dirTree.SelectedItem == null)?

Comment: Yes, that gives the same result and message.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do your check to make sure its's not null and then you can do dirTree.SelectedItem.Equals("") or cast to the expected type.